# High battery consumption issues with windows 8.1, Any solution?

Tags: lumia, settings, 8.1, battery, lumia-520

I have recently upgraded to windows phone 8.1 developer's preview for my Nokia Lumia 520. 
With its touchy features I got a side-effect, that is, the battery gets low very quickly.

Any specific reason And how do i get out of it?

Is any trick in settings or anywhere? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of 8.1 are you using? There are two builds, with one of them allegedly fixing the battery performance issues...

Answer (score 1):

An update was released soon after the launch on Windows Phone 8.1 Preview for developers. You’re on OS version 8.10.12359.845 if you are. This update will put you at OS version 8.10.12382.878.

Head to **settings > phone update > check for update** to grab the new version and start the installation.

Comment: Yes I am using 8.10.12359.84 version. Have checked it.

Comment: According to the answer.. There is an update available which will resolve your issue. :)